# Why does .NET differentiate String from Character?

Tags: .net, string, character, base-class-library

Isn't having String enough?

Just as **an** example, 
why can String class lets you pass either char array or string array to its [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method? 
while it's perfectly valid to use just string version?

1. [String.Split Method (Char[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx)
2. [String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

Comment: Because sometimes a character is a more accurate abstraction than a string with length of one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are an abstraction for arrays of characters. As such, they are technically reference types (although, unlike most references types, they are immutable) even for single-char strings.  Characters, on the other hand are actually value types themselves. ([MSDN 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe), [MSDN 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay))

[C# Replace Performance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace-performance) shows a performance implication of this, in which using character arrays is 4x faster than using string arrays.

Comment: The framework doesn't treat strings as value types at all. Just because they're immutable doesn't stop them from being used as reference types, through and through.

Comment: There's also a small performance benefit to using chars when applicable when calling `StringBuilder.Append()`.